# Android--Why I can't see the VIEW directly?

Tags: android

I've built a new view named myview including `OnDraw` section.

And I tried to use  `setContentView(myview)` in `Oncreate`, however, it failed and showed some error.

Then I use `addview` function to add this view to my original layout, and `setContent(R.layout.main)`

Finally I can see the result on the screen.

What was the problem ? Why I can't directly use  `setContentView(myview)` to show the result ?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
       myview2=new MyView2(this);
       setContentView(R.layout.main2);
       RelativeLayout layout= ( RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.dashpage);        
       layout.addView(myview2);

    }

class MyView2 extends View{

        public MyView2(Context context) { 
            super(context);
        }
        Bitmap themometer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  
                   R.drawable.the);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
        Bitmap themometerbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(themometer, 0, 0, themometer.getWidth(),  
                themometer.getHeight(), matrix2, true);

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas2)
        {
            canvas2.drawBitmap(themometerbmp,90,5,null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mice suggests you need to provide more details and your code. Are you inflating your View by the way?

Comment: The error is that the system will crash immediately.

Later on , I will post my code here. It can work correctly,however,what I mean is that I have to add view to my layout instead of applying my view with setContentView directly.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output associated with the crash? Also why not use a simple ImageView instead of your view?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `setContentView` is the problem. You are trying to use a drawable. Try this:

Add a function in MyView2:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
        drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Then, instead of

```
Bitmap themometer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.the);
```

use

```
Bitmap themometer = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.the));
```